# How to find the error in the logic of my code?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, bubble-sort

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    char str1[50][50],temp[50];
    int lim,i,j,res;
    printf("Enter the number of strings: ");
    scanf("%d",&lim);
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",str1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<lim-1;j++)
        {
            res=strcmp(str1[i],str1[j]);
            if(res==1)
            {
                strcpy(temp,str1[i]);
                strcpy(str1[i],str1[j]);
                strcpy(str1[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        puts(str1[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use bubble sort to sort the strings entered by the user. But the result isn't coming out right.

Is there any error in my logic in the `if` statement?

Comment: You really should not use `strcpy` as it is particularly vulnerable, especially when used with user input as in your example. Look up alternatives such as `strncpy`

Comment: @h0r53 Not that it will add any security to the code. The issue is starting from `scanf`.

Comment: @h0r53 `strncpy` has its own problems. Especially the copied string may end up without a NUL terminator.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I saw people what were told to replace `strcpy(str1, str2)` with `strncpy`.. And they did `strncpy(str1, str2, strlen(str2))` (well, sometimes cared to +1) :D

Comment: In a bubble sort you compare adjacent elements and swap when needed. This code starts from `i` and compares `str1` at `i` to each other element. Once you've swapped `str1[i]` with something else, you aren't comparing it to adjacent elements anymore because `i` will be skipped in the next loop iteration. That's the logic flaw.

Comment: Hint: not sure if this is the problem: but `if (res==1)` is wrong and should be `if (res>0)`. Read the documentation of `strcmp` carefully, especially the part about the return value.

Comment: Correct, @h0r53, the OP does not present a valid Bubble Sort.  But they do appear to present a mostly-valid *Selection* Sort.

Answer (score 1):

As @h0r53 observed in comments, what you have implemented is not [at all] a Bubble Sort.  It is almost a Selection Sort, but it has incorrect inner-loop iteration bounds that seem somewhat reminiscent of a Bubble Sort.  The combination is broken.  From a Selection Sort perspective, it is wrong because you never consider the last element, and it is inefficient because you needlessly reconsider the lead elements that have already been sorted.

The key part of an algorithmically correct Selection Sort version might look like this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < lim; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < lim; j++) {  // These bounds are changed vs. the original
            // Compare each subsequent element with element i:
            res = strcmp(str1[i], str1[j]);
            if (res > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, str1[i]);
                strcpy(str1[i], str1[j]);
                strcpy(str1[j], temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, this would be an algorithmically correct Bubble Sort version:

```
    // for (i = 0; i < lim; i++) {  // particularly inefficient; note: no i in the loop body
    for (; lim > 1; lim--) {  
        for (j = 0; j < lim - 1; j++) {  // Almost, but not quite, the same as the original
            // Compare each element but the last with the following one:
            res = strcmp(str1[j], str1[j + 1]);
            if (res > 0) {
                strcpy(temp, str1[j]);
                strcpy(str1[j], str1[j + 1]);
                strcpy(str1[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

This implementation decreases `lim` by 1 on each outer-loop iteration because each iteration will cause the next one of the largest elements to bubble to its correct final position, where it does not need to be considered again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can run if you change the sorting statement as below:
From:

```
    for(i=0;i<lim;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<lim-1;j++)
        {
            res=strcmp(str1[i],str1[j]);
            if(res==1)
            {
                strcpy(temp,str1[i]);
                strcpy(str1[i],str1[j]);
                strcpy(str1[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

to

```
    while (cont) {
        cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lim - 1; i++)
        {
            res=strcmp(str1[i],str1[i+1]);
            if (res > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp,str1[i]);
                strcpy(str1[i],str1[i+1]);
                strcpy(str1[i+1],temp);
                cont = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```